# Change ImageView image by clicking btnChange

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am new to javafx. Recently i try to do a program which can change an image in imageview by click a button to switch. Errors occur

```
@FXML
private ImageView imgView;
@FXML
private Button btnChange;

@FXML
void changeImage (ActionEvent event) throws IOException
{
    Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource("Yuumi.jpg").toString());
    imgView.setImage(image);

}
```

[This is my project and the FXML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t3Ic.png)

---

This is my FXML.fxml code
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vQiMXxrRWd84YWcqmQO3xQx0Q1DdIBYt

---

The errors
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UwVzeEAp1YlhwP0xHZfxnioxEk2BAoC4

---

My FXML controller https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-7bAKoLhbLcC5bR4_boCG_O57sXPZpX_/view

Comment: Your screen capture does not display the entire stack trace. Somewhere in the actual stack trace there should be a reference to the code you wrote. So post the full stack trace. And **please** try using "copy/paste" rather than posting a screen capture. You should also post your code so that we can correlate it with the stack trace. And also use "copy/paste" to post your code. No screen capture.

Comment: The entire trace  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UwVzeEAp1YlhwP0xHZfxnioxEk2BAoC4

Comment: We require the necessary info to be posted in the question itself. A link to code/error messages is insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stack trace you provided, the problem is clearly stated, namely

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
>   java.awt.Button field application.MainController.btnChange to
>   javafx.scene.control.Button

Looks like you imported `java.awt.Button` instead of `javafx.scene.control.Button` in your code - that I also asked you to provide and which you didn't, so I can't verify that this really is your problem.

**EDIT**

Selected lines from your `MainController` class...

```
import java.awt.Button;

@FXML
private Button btnChange;
```

Can you see the problem?

Comment: My main java https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oCiBMqL0q3gNjckfbhwaaCRGhUJeMcXQ
my FXML.fxml code https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vQiMXxrRWd84YWcqmQO3xQx0Q1DdIBYt

Comment: My FXML controller https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-7bAKoLhbLcC5bR4_boCG_O57sXPZpX_

Comment: I think you can search through your code for `java.awt.Button`, can't you? You probably just need to replace it with `javafx.scene.control.Button`. Or do you just want me to do all the work for you?

Comment: Its working. Thank you so much